# Thank-You page not displaying for Pay-Later contributions

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

Recently while testing a new contribution page I noticed that CiviCRM is no longer displaying a thank-you page when a donor selects the ‘Pay later’ option. Instead of a Thank-You page, CiviCRM goes directly to a fresh (unpopulated) contribution page. All contribution pages on two WordPress sites I manage now act this way. The Thank-You page displays as usual if a payment portal such as PayPal is selected.

Pending donations are properly recorded in the database, and CiviCRM sends a Thank-You email, but the missing Thank-You page can confuse donors into thinking there was a glitch, some of who immediately make a second donation. Also, the Thank-You page normally shows the Pay-later instructions, which is important given that Thank-You emails often end up in junk folders.

I don’t know when the Thank-You page ceased to appear for Pay-later donors, but I see duplicate Pay-later donations back as far as Nov.30, 2021, a day after updating sites to CiviCRM version 5.43.2, though we are currently running 5.50.2. The last time I tested a contribution page on either site the Thank-You page worked normally, but that has probably been over a year ago.

Before I report an issue, I wonder if anyone else has noticed this problem, or if the Pay-later Thank-You page is working normally for anyone running a fairly current version of CiviCRM for WordPress (if so, what version)?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem causing the thank-you page to misbehave on pay-later - while updating a few months ago I missed adding a couple definitions to the settings file (CRM_CRED_KEYS and CIVICRM_SIGN_KEYS). After adding the php code to set these keys the thank-you page displays properly.